# Rails 4.2 What's currently the best way to incorporate instant messaging in an app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, instant-messaging, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I've been reading that Rails 5 (anyone know when that will be release?) will be incorporating support for websockets that will make instant messaging easier to incorporate. But I'm trying to set something up now for an fairly built up app. If all goes well, I could have quite a number of users soon, so it will need to scale as well.

I've looked at Ryan Bates's Private Pub which is kind of old, [Heroku's websocket example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets) (I'm deployed on Heroku), [Websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails), actioncable, and maybe a few others. Most look pretty involved, so I'm wondering what my best option is, or if Rails 5 will be out soon and I should just wait for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm biased towards [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi), which is built for scaling (using Redis) and [can be used to easily add websocket support to your existing web-app](http://www.plezi.io/docs/with_rack_app)... but than again, I might not be objective about it.

There are two ways to run Plezi within Rails - either merging the apps/servers (using the [Iodine HTTP/Websocket server](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine)) or using Redis to sync the two apps.

Both ways are easy to set up.

To use Plezi within your Rails app, add `plezi` to your `Gemfile` and remove any references to 'thin' or 'puma' or any other server from your `Gemfile` - this should allow Iodine to take over automatically. Than place `Plezi.app` as a middleware in your app.

You can either include a pre-made Plezi app by requiring it's files, or - even easier - you could write the code into one of the Rails files (maybe using the 'initializers', 'helpers' or 'models' folders).

Try adding the following code for a chatroom server:

```
require 'plezi'

# do you need automated redis support?
# require 'redis'
# ENV['PL_REDIS_URL'] = "redis://user:password@localhost:6379"

class BroadcastCtrl
    def index
        # we can use the websocket echo page to test our server, 
        # just remember to update the server address in the form.
        redirect_to 'http://www.websocket.org/echo.html'
    end
    def on_message data
        # try replacing the following two lines are with:
        # self.class.broadcast :_send_message, data
        broadcast :_send_message, data
        response << "sent."
    end
    def _send_message data
        response << data
    end
end

route '/broadcast', BroadcastCtrl
```

This allows us to inject some Rails magic into Plezi and some Plezi magic into Rails... For instance, it's easy to save a user's websocket UUID and send them updates:

```
require 'plezi'

# do you need automated redis support?
# require 'redis'
# ENV['PL_REDIS_URL'] = "redis://user:password@localhost:6379"

class UserNotifications
    def on_open
        get_current_user.websocket_uuid = uuid
        get_current_user.save
    end
    def on_close
        # wrap all of the following in a transaction, or scaling might
        # create race conditions and corrupt UUID data
        return unless UsersController.get_current_user.websocket_uuid == uuid
        get_current_user.websocket_uuid = nil 
        get_current_user.save
    end
    def on_message data
         # get data from user and use it somehow
    end
    protected
    def get_current_user
         # # use your authentication system here, maybe:
         # @user ||= UserController.auth_user(cookies[:my_session_id])
    end
    def send_message data
        response << data
    end
end

route '/', UserNotifications

# and in your UserController 

def UserController < ApplicationController
    def update
        # your logic and than send notification:
        data = {}
        UserNotifications.unicast @user.websocket_uuid, :send_message, data.to_json
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to use it in my rails app, but i'm a bit confused on how to do so. is there an example rails app that i can look at? i've also been getting this error: "tried to update execution permissions. this is system dependent and might have failed." do you know what that's about? It won't let me run the default plezi app from plezi install.

Comment: the message `"tried to update execution permissions. this is system dependent and might have failed"` isn't an error. Plezi always writes this because the execution permission update is based on MacOSX and should work on unix-like systems but not on windows. It's jus a tweek that allows you to run the application from the OS's GUI as well as the terminal UI.... The rest I will try to write while editing the answer.

Comment: thanks for your support. i've found that just installing the gem slows down javascript considerable, at least in development mode. is that normal? i'm still having a hard time wrapping my head around where everything goes and fits together. i think i might hold off on including websockets for a little while.

Comment: That's not really normal. Although, version 0.11.0 should be coming out soon, with GRHttp's new version, so that might fix the issue... Still, I am super surprised. The only thing I can think of is that the JavaScript waits for the connection to close while the server keeps the connection alive... You could try adding the `connection: close` header and see if that helps.

Comment: @baron816 - version 0.11.0 is out and I was wondering if the issue persists... Could you check, since the issue does not appear on my system?

Comment: yep, definitely still there. there must be a conflict with something else i'm using. but i definitely can't use it like that because there's a huge delay from when i submit a message to when jquery adds it to the message box, in addition to other things thats aren't correct.

Comment: Wow, I really wish I knew what the issue was and could fix it. I'm using TurboLinks and it runs smoothly... If you get any error messages or if you have any information about the issue, please let me know or post it on GitHub. I thank you for your time and quick reply.

Comment: i'm using jquery-turbolinks, which is a little different.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 has been released.  I recommend you upgrade and go with actioncable.

In the long run it should be the best option as it will be part of the Rails core and it is developed, used and maintained by Basecamp.  They will invest enough effort to make sure it is stable, scalable and accepted by the community.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Action cable is what I'm going to end up using. I spent a solid amount of time trying to incorporate into my app, but it does seem to rely on Rails 5 for anything but the most basic implementation. And it's definitely not finished. So I've decided to hold off until it's all ready.

Comment: Is this still true?  Can you use the actioncable gem with rails 4?

Comment: I've not been able to use actioncable with rails4, it depends on actionpack5 which depends on rails 5